# How can I redirect to another template when the submit button is pressed in Alert Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I have a alert function in controller.js:

```
function showAlertFinishedTest() {
var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'Finished',
    scope: $scope,
    template: 'Are you sure to submit the result?'
});

confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
    if (res) {
        console.log('Submit file json!');
    } else {
        console.log('Get back to the test!');
    }
});
};
```

How can I redirect to another template when press submit button in if(res){}?

Thanks for all of your answering!

Comment: You can use $state.go("statename);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject $state into the controller and use `$state.go('[your state name]');` see the doc for UI router here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Thanks, I will adapt your solution into my project!

Comment: Perfect. Let me know if you run into any more issues. Pls accept the answer.